# Smallest element in an array that is repeated exactly ‘k’ times

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, c++11

This is a problem from [GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/?p=155597) and I have tried to solve it on my own and I have written this code.

> Given an array of size n, the goal is to find out the smallest number
>   that is repeated exactly ‘k’ times where k > 0? Assume that array has
>   only positive integers and 1 <= arr[i] < 1000 for each i = 0 to n -1.
>
> Examples:
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> arr[] = {2 2 1 3 1}
> k = 2
> ```
>
> Output: 1
>
> Explanation:
>
> Here in array:
>
> - 2 is repeated 2 times
> - 1 is repeated 2 times
> - 3 is repeated 1 time
>
> Hence 2 and 1 both are repeated 'k' times
>
> i.e 2 and min(2, 1) is 1
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> arr[] = {3 5 3 2}
> k = 1
> ```
>
> Output: 2
>
> Explanation:
>
> Both 2 and 5 are repeating 1 time but min(5, 2) is 2

How can I improve this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

template<class T>
void findElement(std::vector<T>& vec, int k)
{
  std::map<T, int> count;
  for(T x : vec)
  {
    count[x]++;
  }

  typename std::map<T, int>::iterator itr;
  for(itr = count.begin(); itr != count.end(); itr++)
  {
    if(itr->second == k)
    {
      std::cout << itr->first <<'\n';
      return;
    }
  }
  std::cerr << "No such element \n ";
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<char> v;
  v.push_back('r');
  v.push_back('t');
  v.push_back('q');
  v.push_back('r');
  v.push_back('u');
  v.push_back('q');
  v.push_back('s');
  int k;
  std::cout << " Enter the number of repetitions you want : ";
  std::cin >> k;
  std::cout << "The smallest element that has " << k <<" reptition is : ";
  findElement(v, k);
}
```

Comment: There is not much to talk about, except algorithm design. And may be other possible solution and situations in which they would be better. Though the current one is good for casual use already.

Comment: @Incomputable what I have to improve? I have used `std::map` instead of `std::unordered_map` because it sorts the element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Interface

- There's no point in limiting your function inputs to a vector. You can take two input iterators instead. It'll make your function more flexible and more "standard library-like".
- One function should do one focused thing. Your function finds such an element  **and**  prints it as the same time. These concerns are unrelated. You can return `std::optional<T>` instead to represent either such an element or its absence. Note: it works for C++17 only. You can use `boost::optional` or return a smart pointer if it's not available.

### Modern C++

- There's no need for things like this anymore:

  ```
  typename std::map<T, int>::iterator itr;
  for(itr = count.begin(); itr != count.end(); itr++)
  ```

  `for (const auto& kv : count)` is much better, isn't it?
- You can also use initialization list to create a vector with the elements you need: `std::vector<char> v({'r', 't',..., 's'})`

### Performance

- `for (T x : vec)` creates an unnecessary copy. Use `for (const T& x : vec)` or `for (const auto& T : vec)` instead.
- You can also use `std::unordered_map` to do the counting and then choose the smallest element (it's more efficient because one can find the minimum in `O(n)`. It's "easier" than sorting the input). One caveat: you need a hash function for `T` in this case. You can pass it as another template parameter, defaulted to `std::hash`.

Comment: One could also sort the vector/range and try to find the value with the appearance count. Though that would be sort plus linear pass, which is probably not good. The map would traverse only amount of distinct elements in a range. I guess it all depends on circumstances.

Comment: @Incomputable Yes, I believe that either option (map, unorded_map, sorting the vector) is reasonable.

Comment: How to take to input iterators instead of vector?

Comment: @janos, the main issue here in my opinion is returning the iterator to the element inside of the container. Returning value rarely has any use in my experience. And it is weird for search to return found element by value anyway. Though your algorithm would be good for the specific use case.

Comment: @coder, the same way you take any other template argument.

Comment: @Incomputable then what will be equivalent for `for(const T& x : vec)` when  using iterators?

Comment: @coder, `while (first != last) {//dosomething}`, though don't forget to increment `first`. Pre-increment preferably.

Comment: Please can anyone write the whole code passing input iterators as parameter? I am having problem to copy values in `std::map` and to count them and then display the values.

Comment: @coder, [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/142902/93301) should be easy enough to get grasp of how  to wield iterators. I recommend trying to find any other range algorithm on this site, they usually mention iterators.

Comment: I have defined map `std::map<InputItr, int> count;` and I have replaced `for(T x : vec)
  {
    count[x]++;
  }`  with  `while(start != end)
  {
    count[*start]++;
    ++start;
  }` and to display key and values in map `for(auto itr : count)
{
  std::cout << itr->first << " " << itr->second << "\n";
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64501/discussion-between-coder-and-incomputable).

Comment: Have you actually benchmarked the difference between sorted and unsorted maps, over a range of sizes?  It would improve this answer greatly if you were to include some of your findings to show *how much* difference it makes to performance.

Comment: @TobySpeight No, I haven't. I suggested using it because an unordered map is faster on average in terms of time complexity.

Comment: Thant's a shame - I think you're right (as we'll perform `n` lookups or inserts, which we'd like to be O(1), and then iterate over the `m` distinct values to find those with `count == k`), but it would be nice to back that up with measurements (including pathological case where all elements are the same, or all different).  Maybe I'll research this and write my own answer - though I'm looking quite busy just now, so don't hold your breath waiting for me!

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the problem statement, a few obvious solutions come to mind:

1. Count of many of each number there is and take the smallest with 'k' entries. This is what you do and as you are using a `std::map` with `log(m)` insertion where 'm' is the number of distinct elements (bounded by 1000) so you have \$O(n\log(m))\$ run time and \$O(m)\$ memory.
2. Sort the input vector and scan linearly from the start until you find something that repeats 6 times. As you have to sort the whole thing you get \$O(nlogn)\$ time and \$O(n)\$ memory unless you can modify the input array.

But there is a better way:

```
/**
 * Will find the smallest value in 'vec' that is repeated 'k' times.
 *
 * It is assumed that values of 'vec' are [1, 1000[ as per 
 * problem description. 
 */
void findElement(const std::vector<unsigned int>& vec, int k){
  constexpr auto max_value = 1000U;
  std::array<unsigned int, max_value> freq;
  freq.fill(k);
  for(auto& value : vec){
      freq.at(value)--;
  }
  for(std::size_t f = 0; f < freq.size(); ++f){
      if(0 == freq[f]){
          std::cout << f <<'\n';
          return;
      }
  }
  std::cerr << "No such element\n";
}
```

The raw array is actually faster as this code only performs \$O(n+m)\$ work which is less than \$O(nlogm)\$. Yes it's not as "generic" as the template method and won't work for all `T`. But it doesn't need to be able to do that for the task.

One could solve this using `std::unordered_map` as well, and the big O time is the same:

```
template<typename Container>
void findElement(const Container& container, int k){
    std::unordered_map<Container::value_type, int> freq;
    for(auto& value : container){
        freq[value]++;
    }
    auto smallest = freq.end();
    for(auto& entry : freq){
        if(entry.second == k && (smallest != freq.end() || entry.first < smallest.first )){
            smallest = entry;
        }
    }

    if(smallest != freq.end()){
        std::cout << smallest.first <<'\n';
    }
    else{
        std::cerr << "No such element\n";¨
    }
}
```

The algorithm is essentially the same with one minor difference, the approach with the `std::unordered_map` may not terminate early on finding the first element with exactly 'k' occurrences as the array based algorithm can. This means that the `unordered_map` version must visit exactly all 'M<1000' unique values in 'vec' including some overhead from traversing a sparse hash-map,  while the array version on average only needs to visit '1000/2' of the possible values.

So they have different cases where they are faster. For example a degenerate case such as K=3 , {999,999,999} is faster with unordered_map as you only visit one unique element but with the array solution you need to (very quickly) scan through the 998 elements in the array. But on average on random sets the array solution is expected to be slightly faster by a constant factor as both have the same big O time.

Comment: The mentioned O(n+m) method is of course the right one, but it has nothing to do with the term 'brute force' (misleading). It is called bucket sort.

Comment: Or one could make 1. just as efficient as the array solution (and support arbitrary sized elements) by using an unordered_map.

Comment: @mafu you are correct, I used the term loosely to refer to the fact of not using any data structure other than plain, fixed size array.

Comment: @Voo afaik `std::hash<int>` isn't required to return the argument unmodified. Which means that you need to compare all elements of the unordered map to find the minimum which prevents the early exit the array solution has. The asymptotic performance is the same but the time constant differs to the advantage of the array solution which also avoids dynamic memory allocations which also take a short time. But no work is less work than some work. Also the task is to solve the programming challenge, not write code for an "enterprise" system.

Comment: @Emily You have to iterate through elements in the array to find the first non-0 value, which the dictionary solution can do just the same (it doesn't matter what the hash function is as long as it is reasonably "good" which is trivial for ints). The only difference in performance will be that the dictionary has a relatively more expensive indexing operation.

Comment: @Voo Yes but the difference is that in the array you only iterate to the first element with  value 'k'. As you cannot guarantee that elements in the unordered_map are in order (it's kind of part of the name), you have to visit *all* elements. This is slower in practice *on average* although the asymptotic and worst case time is the same.

Comment: @Emily Accessing an element has O(1) for both versions and that's all you're doing there (in one case you check whether the key exists in the other whether the value is not 0). So asymptotic growth for the average case is still identical.

Comment: @Emily, I don't like downvoting answers that are well-intentioned and obviously taken some time to produce, but I really believe this code is a bad example.  I really think you shouldn't present this with no bounds checking, even with your final sentence.  Where does the magic `1000` come from?  Are you sure that local storage is a good place for the array (both in terms of overflowing stack and in terms of the safety risks of overrunning either end of the array with out-of-bounds indexes)?  You generally write really good answers, but this is uncharacteristically weak from you.  Again, sorry!

Comment: @TobySpeight I code to the problem. It's throw-away code for a one-off programming challenge that is guaranteed to have well-formed input and won't run on any other system than the online judge and my test machine with data I control. I don't like to expend too much energy on such things. Yet as you asked so nicely I went ahead and added bounds checking and all that other jazz. As for heap vs stack. I prefer to use the stack when possible as it's just cleaner and avoiding unnecessary memory allocations is good practice.

Comment: Actually, the comment stating the assumption really makes a world of difference to the answer (because the code for review was a template, I made the mistake of assuming it was supposed to be generic).  I've retracted my downvote and conferred an upvote instead.  And I apologise for ragging you on something that wasn't required (just that without the comment, I'd lost the context!).